# Streaming audio via html5/js (a la radio)?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, stream

Is there a library or technique out there that will let me embed a streamed audio source in a webpage? I've seen other SO answers recommending audio.js for similar requests, but it looks like that will only let you pick a single audio file.

While I guess I could put a bunch of effort into making a file-like audio stream, I feel like there has to be a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best thing for the job is one of the use-cases of [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-08/); will update if problems crop up or something better rears its head.